# RNASeq NMF clustering using what kind of expression unit?

Tags: r, rna-seq, nmf

I would need some help regarding certain points in a RNASeq gene expression analysis (sorry if there are stupid questions, its my first project and i have no capable supervision). My workflow is the following:

- TMM normalization
- obtaining CPMs
- filtering CPMs that are under 1 in half the samples
- obtaining log2(CPM) - after I perform this step I get Inf values, should I treat those values as NA and remove them or should I use CPM + 1 (I know that adding +1 introduces certain bias)?
- apply Median Absolute Deviation and use different thresholds to subset data
- apply NMF clustering and find cluster specific genes and samples
- use the sample clusters to obtain DEGs (using DESeq2) and proceed with GSEA

Now for the questions.. Firstly, I tried to look for the best practices in scientific papers and on forums but they vary in a huge manner.

In papers, such as https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26909576/ the authors use log2(CPM) for NMF clustering analysis, while looking online at other suggestions, they all suggest using variance stabilizing transformation or z-scores etc. Now, what I'm trying to do is find subtype specific genes and significant DE genes based on those subtypes.

From what I understand, VST transformation is ideal but why do all the papers that I've found only use TPM/CPM for subsequent analysis such as NMF clustering (other papers only mention gene expression or I missed that)?

I've tried both ways, with log2(CPM) and with VST and I've found that VST clusters contain more genes and tend to be of equal size (both genes and samples clusters) while log2(CPM) clusters returns a cluster 3 times bigger than the second (both for genes and samples). Both VST and log2(CPM) clusters were selected by the best cophenetic coef and also samples had silhouette widths above 0.6.

Now, what should be the best approach considering that I'm expected to write a decent paper with this dataset.

Thank you in advance!

PS: all the above are done in R